# Read a file line-by-line instead of read file into memory

Tags: python, file

I´m having some trouble with reading a file line-by-line, instead of reading the the file into memory. As of right now, I'm reading the file into memory, and it works perfect. However, If i try to read the file line-by-line, I only get zero when I type 'print(B)'. My question is, does anyone have a good command for reading the file line-by-line in python? My code looks like this:

```
def read(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f: #open the file

        for line in f:

            A = sum(float(line) for line in f)

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:

            B = sum(float(line)**2 for line in f)

            print(B)

read('file.txt')
```

Comment: in both your example your are reading line by line.

Comment: This works fine for me: [see here](https://repl.it/@pyelias/WindyLatestGenerics)

Comment: Please provide some sample input, the result you expect, and the result you're getting instead.

Comment: Ok, but have to use the "with open(filename, 'r') as f:" - command again. Otherwise, I can´t print. Can I solve this without using the "with open" command twice?

Comment: Show us the sample input and output.

Comment: You can just use `f.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer in stead of reopening the file.

Comment: Note that your `for` loops only iterate once; the loop reads the first line, but the generator expression consumes the rest of the file.

Comment: Ok, if I type: 'def read(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            A = sum(float(line) for line in f)
            
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            
            B = sum(float(line)**2 for line in f)
    
            print(B)
' I get 1040.5627229197985. If I type: 'def read(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            A = sum(float(line) for line in f)
                     
            B = sum(float(line)**2 for line in f)
    
            print(B) I get 0

Comment: I´dont wan´t to use the "with open(filename, 'r') as f:" twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this right for you?

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

A = sum(float(line) for line in data)
B = sum(float(line)**2 for line in data)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it with only one pass over the file. You have to abandon the nice built-in `sum` and do it yourself:

```
def read(filename):
    A, B = 0, 0
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            x = float(line)
            A += x
            B += x**2
    print(A)
    print(B)
```

Also note that you are actually iterating in a weird way over the lines of the file, since you have an outer loop `for line in f` and an inner loop in the `sum` that also runs over `for line in f`. Since `f` is an iterator, this means that the outer loop will only get to the first line, the inner loop will consume all other lines and sum them and then the outer loop has nothing else to process and quits. You should be able to see this by noting that the `print(B)` statement is only executed once.

Answer (score 1):

To return to the beginning of the file, use [seek](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm):

```
def read(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as f: #open the file

        A = sum(float(line) for line in f)
        f.seek(0)
        B = sum(float(line)**2 for line in f)

            print(B)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your input was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Original problem is that you've hit the end of the file and need to go back to the start to iterate over it again. You can do this in a single iteration through the file, split into two and then sum.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    A, B = map(sum, zip(*((x, x**2) for x in map(float, f))))
```