# Get the last list using append

Tags: python, list

Let's assume I have a function that imports the file containing the following numbers:

```
18.18
18.25
17.5
.
.
```

.`

where each number has it own line.

Then I use the append function on these numbers and I get the following output.

[image]

My question is if there is a command to save the end list, i.e. the list that is generated when all elements of the data structure have been added? I only want to have the final list.

Comment: Save what? to where? This question needs much more context (who knows, maybe even a [mcve]) to be answerable.

Comment: Simply move the print after the loop so you only print the list that has had all its items appended.

Comment: Why are you using `append` if you don't want them all?  You can get the last element of a list with `[-1]`.

Comment: Ok, so if I read in this file containg all these numbers using the append function, the append() appends a passed object object into the existing list. I wonder how I can get an output that only shows the final list.

Comment: You should look at the [answer you already got on a similar question you asked][1]. 

Don't use append, use:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    line for line in data

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259470/read-a-file-line-by-line-instead-of-read-file-into-memory

Comment: Is there any other command, besides form append(), so that I would get the final list exclusively?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [answer you already got on a similar question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259470/read-a-file-line-by-line-instead-of-read-file-into-memory).

Don't use append, use:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
final_list = [line for line in data]
```

If you don't understand why this works, try searching for python list comprehension, the first one on my search was [this link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python